# Sun illuminates tall objects

Tags: rendering, lighting

I'm making a site model as part of an architecture project, and currently the tip of the cathedral is illuminated when the time for the sun is set to midnight. I'm not sure why this is happening or how to fix it.
Here is the model rendered at 12pm:
[image: Lighting at 12pm]

Here is the model rendered at 12am:
[image]

A quick solution I found was to keyframe the sun strength to 0 at sunrise and sunset, and to 1000 at mid day. This works however I'm not sure if it is 100% realistic to how the sun would really work.

Answer (score 1):

This could be happening because there is no geometry to block the light.

At 12AM, the sun is below the horizon, so the Earth should cast a large shadow on the city. In your case, however, there is no geometry to block this light, and so the sun is able to shine on your tower from below.

You could create a huge plane at z=0 to emulate the Earth's shadow. Alternatively, as you suggested, you can animate the sun's strength to make it dark at night.

Comment: Adding a large plane seems to have fixed the issue! Thank you :)